# Flask python ,URL not found

Tags: python, flask

When I run the following code snippet, I get a `URL not found` error. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Thanks.

```py
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/set')
def setcookie():
    res = make_response("<h2>The cookie is set</h2>")
    res.set_cookie('framework', 'flask')
    return res

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `@` to your `app.route` like below:

```py
@app.route('/set')
def setcookie():
    res = make_response("<h2>The cookie is set</h2>")
    res.set_cookie('framework', 'flask')
    return res
```